# How to Mimic Server Down(503) With Windows 8 Phone Emulator, IIS Express, Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-phone, http-status-code-503

Does anyone know how to get a 503 error to occur when doing a call from code in a windows phone application.

I tried by not running my web api project and just loading up and doing a call to that project but it just comes back 403 and not 503.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the 503 error with this line of code in your WebAPI controller:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, "Service unavailable");
```

Comment: but a) won't I have to do that in every method? b) how does this even work if the webapi is not even running. I still don't know if this is just because of the emulator or if something iis express or what.

Comment: I thought you wanted to simulate a 503 error. Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For some reason when I have a webapi project, and I don't run it, I load up the emulator and send a request through RestSharp to the webapi that is not on, I get a response of 404 instead of 503. I am wondering how to correct this, Is there a setting in IISExpress, Windows Phone emulator or what?